# Routing problems .NET 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes

I am using routing through Global.asax.

I want http://www.website.com/ad/123 to lead to http://www.website.com/ad.aspx?id=123

This is working fine using:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("AdById", "ad/{cid}", "~/ad.aspx");
```

I had to "de-route" the js and css files and images, so I have some handlers for that:

```
routes.Add("AdImagesRoute", new Route("ad/graphics/{filename}.{ext}", new ImageRouteHandler())); 
routes.Add("AdJSRoute", new Route("ad/scripts/{filename}.js", new JSRouteHandler())); 
routes.Add("AdCSSRoute", new Route("ad/styles/{filename}.css", new CSSRouteHandler()));
```

Now I also want to "decorate" the URL, so I want something like this:

http://www.website.com/ad/123/House%20For%20Sale

to also lead to http://www.website.com/ad.aspx?id=123

so I added this one:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("AdByIdWithBlah", "ad/{cid}/{blah}", "~/ad.aspx");
```

But now the problem is that when the client goes to this url: http://www.website.com/ad/123, the javascripts are requested like http://www.website.com/ad/scripts/scriptfile.js which makes the routing think it's an ad number and some 'blah' and redirect to ad.aspx.

So I need to somehow tell the Routing that if cid is not a number (because it's a folder) or blah ends with .js or .css then don't route.

I tried this:

```
Route adwithblahroute = new Route("ad/{cid}/{blah}", new RouteValueDictionary() {{"blah", "blah"}} , new RouteValueDictionary() { { "cid", @"^\d+$" }, {"blah", @"^[^.]$"} }, new BlahRouteHandler());
routes.Add(adwithblahroute);
```

But now I get a 404 if I request http://www.website.com/ad/123/sometext

I hope someone can help me fix this problem.

---- EDIT ----

BTW, This is the BlahRouteHandler:

```
public class BlahRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            int cid = 0;
            string filepath;
            if (Int32.TryParse(requestContext.RouteData.Values["cid"] as string, out cid))
            {
                filepath = requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/ad.aspx");
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            return null;
        }   
    }
```

------ ADDED ------

Just for Google'rs, I have found a one line solution, I don't need the handler or class, as it seems. This line did the trick:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("AdByIdWithBlah", "ad/{cid}/{blah}", "~/ad.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary() { { "blah", "blah" } }, new RouteValueDictionary() { { "cid", @"^\d+$" } } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route class which derives `Route` and only implement the route matching in it (let the base handle everything else).

By doing so you can check if the second path part really is a number.

Then just add it as the first route in the dictionary.

```
public class MyCustomRoute : Route
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var url = httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
        var relativeUri = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Remove(0, url.Length);

        // split url here
        // return null if the second path part is not a number
        // else invoke base.GetRouteData
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'll need a little more help implementing it. I tried adding the class to Global.asax, splitting the relativeUri and all, as you suggest, but I don't know how to add it.
`routes.Add(new AdBlahRoute("ad/{cid}/{blah}", new BlahRouteHandler()));` But this doesn't work, as "'System.Web.Routing.Route' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments" and "'ASP.global_asax.AdBlahRoute' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments"

Comment: All routes must be named (first argument)

Comment: Is this correct?:
`public class AdBlahRoute : Route
{        
public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
var url = httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/');
var relativeUri = httpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Remove(0, url.Length);
string[] urlparts = relativeUri.Split('/');
try
{
Convert.ToInt32(urlparts[1]);
return base.GetRouteData(httpContext);
}
catch
{
return null;
}   
}
}`

Comment: ...never mind. I got this to work with a one-liner:
`routes.MapPageRoute("AdByIdWithBlah", "ad/{cid}/{blah}", "~/ad.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary() { { "blah", "blah" } }, new RouteValueDictionary() { { "cid", @"^\d+$" } } );`